# How to obtain only positive value in second column

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I use this command

```
awk 'NR%2{t=$1;next}{print $1-t,$2}'
```

to get the distance between two consecutive Y points in a file. But I would like to have all positive numbers. How to get that ? like something as modulus.

```
1577 -46.1492
1577.57 47
1578 -47.6528
1578.87 49
1579 -49.2106
1580 -50.7742
1580.15 51
```

Comment: It is unclear (as you can see from the answers) whether the data that you present is input to your existing awk script or output from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Command: awk '$2 !~ /^-/{print $0}' file

output

1577.57 47
1578.87 49
1580.15 51
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace this:

```
{print $1-t,$2}
```

with this:

```
{if ($2>=0) print $1-t,$2}
```

or,

```
$2 >= 0 { print $1 - t, $2 }
```